# Jenkins not failing on tests that fail in coverage

Tags: django, unit-testing, jenkins, coverage.py

I have Jenkins setup to run tests before anything gets pushed into our QA environment. Recently I added python coverage to check code coverage of the tests.

Issue I have is not I see in the output that tests are failing, but the build still pushes through.

I am running the following in a bash script:

```
coverage run manage.py test --settings=my.settings.jenkins --noinput
```

When I was running the tests normally without coverage, if the test failed, the build would fail, this is no longer the case.

The project is a Django project on Python 3, any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Does it report non-zero exit code to bash ? set -e? http://serverfault.com/questions/143445/what-does-set-e-do-and-why-might-it-be-considered-dangerous

Comment: Not sure how to set "-e" as it is an inline bash script in Jenkins. So in Jenkins you basically make a "build step" where you write some bash that it will execute.

Answer (score 0):

I am hitting the same issue.  My Jenkins build always passes even if Coverage.py has some failing tests (I use the same command as you).

I have come up with a workaround but would ideally like to know if you figured it out?

My workaround uses the TextFinder plugin and I search the console for a specific string which I then fail the build if found....Hack-y I know!

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin